# Mercurial: Obtain the current changeset of a particular file

Tags: mercurial

What is the easiest way of obtaining the changeset version of a particular file in Mercurial? A similar thing that we did for svn was to run "svn --info" in the command line and then obtain the Revision number. Is there any similar approach for Mercurial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept you're missing is that **all files** are all the same changeset.  Unlike SVN you update your entire working dir, not just folders and files.  So you want:

```
hg id
```

to get just the rev number and hash, or

```
hg parents
```

to get info about the comment your current working dir is at, or

```
hg summary
```

for detailed info about what checkout you're at.

Comment: `hg parents FILENAME` works like `hg log -l1 FILENAME`, which is convenient and logical. That is to say it shows the last time that a file was changed, something that you sometimes want to know despite the fact that technically hg does consider the whole repo to be at the same changeset.

Comment: Actually `hg parents FILENAME` works something like `hg log -r 'max(follow("FILENAME"))'`, which shows the last changeset a file was changed *on the current branch*, which is even more convenient.  `hg log -l1 FILENAME` includes changesets which aren't ancestors of the current changeset. **Note:** [hg parents is deprecated](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#parents)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is `hg log -l1 path/to/file`.

Comment: That shows the last revision that file was changed in, but that doesn't necessary show what revision of that file you have in your working dir, which I think was the question.

Oh wait, you're tonfa, clearly you know that. :)